# Dot motion but in wavy format React frame

Tags: css, reactjs, framer-motion

I try to animate this picture as a background using framer motion, and now I am stuck on how to make the movement wavier, and somehow when I look at the picture, I guess the wavy can't be done in one function.

[image: wavy dots]

right now I do these wavy dots, I got it from loading dots that I just duplicate :

```
const loadingContainer = {
  width: "auto",
  height: "1vh",
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "space-around",
  position: "absolute",
  width: "100%",
};

const loadingCircle = {
  display: "block",
  width: "0.4rem",
  height: "0.4rem",
  backgroundColor: "black",
  borderRadius: "50%"
};

const loadingContainerVariants = {
  start: {
    transition: {
      staggerChildren: 0.2
    }
  },
  end: {
    transition: {
      staggerChildren: 0.2
    }
  }
};

const loadingCircleVariants = {
  start: {
    y: "0%",
    width: "1em",
    height: "1em",
  },
  end: {
    y: "20vh",
    width: ".4em",
    height: ".4em",
  }
};

const loadingCircleTransition = {
  duration: 1,
  yoyo: Infinity,
  ease: "easeInOut"
};

export default function ThreeDotsWave() {
  return (
    <motion.div
      style={loadingContainer}
      variants={loadingContainerVariants}
      initial="start"
      animate="end"
    >
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
      <motion.span
        style={loadingCircle}
        variants={loadingCircleVariants}
        transition={loadingCircleTransition}
      />
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

here it is the result : [image]

Comment: What is the question here? Not going to lie I don't think framer-motion or manipulating dom elements, in general, are the way to get a wave effect in the picture.

You will probably want to use WebGL or canvas for that sort of animation. Threejs is a good option for WebGL if that is the way you go

Comment: yes, i also try to look on that, but I don't know how yet, can you show me which doc, or the same implementation ?

Comment: Honestly, that is a field of its own. I don't have a great resource for you. This was helpful for when I started with threejs. https://threejs.org/examples/

Comment: for canvas I would start with the mdn docs